# Handle back press on react native depending on component state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to customize the back navigation event on my react native app. Basically, in the body of the component I render different sections depending on the *currentSection* state variable. What I found out is that the value of *currentSection* inside the *onBackPress* function does not get updated, and apparently always has the value of when it was first called (during the useEffect invocation).

```
    const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState<ProviderDetailSections>(ProviderDetailSections.MAIN);

    useEffect(() => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener(
            "hardwareBackPress",
            onBackPress
        );

        return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener(
            "hardwareBackPress",
            onBackPress
        );
    }, []);

    function onBackPress(): boolean {
        console.log(`onBackPress currentSection: ${currentSection}`);
        if (currentSection === ProviderDetailSections.MAIN) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            setCurrentSection(ProviderDetailSections.MAIN);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The console.log() inside *onBackPress* always logs the same section (MAIN), no matter what is the actual current section. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer

```
const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState<ProviderDetailSections>(ProviderDetailSections.MAIN);

useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        onBackPress
    );

    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        onBackPress
    );
}, []);

function onBackPress(): boolean {
    console.log(`onBackPress currentSection: ${currentSection}`);
        setCurrentSection(ProviderDetailSections.MAIN);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem - the root of it is the fact, that your `useEffect()` function is called only once when the component is rendered, and I think the eventListeners are then created for the component with default values, which means your `currentSection` has default value for your BackHandler functions at all times. What you have to do is add `currentSection` to dependency array in your `useEffect()`.

```
const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState<ProviderDetailSections>(ProviderDetailSections.MAIN);

useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        onBackPress
    );

    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        onBackPress
    );
}, [currentSection]);

function onBackPress(): boolean {
    console.log(`onBackPress currentSection: ${currentSection}`);
    if (currentSection === ProviderDetailSections.MAIN) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        setCurrentSection(ProviderDetailSections.MAIN);
        return true;
    }
}
```